# How to write test cases using React Testing Library for useMutation?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

How to write test cases using React Testing Library for useMutation which covers the `onError` and `onSuccess` callbacks.

```
const useSubmitform = () =>{
    const {mutate}  = useMutation((payload)=>{
       //axios call
    },
    { 
        onError: (error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        },
        onSuccess: (data)=>{
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
  return mutate;
}
```

Comment: Where does the `useMutation` hook come from?

Comment: imported from `react-query`

Comment: Can you show the code of axios call?

Comment: I was confused, React Testing Library builds on top of dom test, how do you use it to test an individual mutation without rendered component.

Comment: The use case is, onclick of button useSubmitform is called. if the axios call returns {status : 400/500} error then onError Is invoked , for { status: 200} onSuccess is invoked

Comment: the component is rendered already

Comment: Mock the API responses during the tests.

Answer (score 3):

React Testing Library builds on dom test. To use it test mutation callback, you need render the callback status in component.

```
function TestComponent() {
  const mutation = useSubmitform()
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={submit}>{ mutation.isLoading ? 'Loading' : 'Submit' }</button>
      { mutation.isError && <p role="alert">failed</p> }
      { mutation.isSuccess && <p role="alert">success</p> }
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
test('test a test exam', () => {
  render(<TestComponent />)
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Submit'))
  waitFor(() => screen.getByRole('alert'))
  expect(screen.getByRole('alert')).toHaveTextContent('success')
})
```

The above code can test mutation results, in addition you can use `msw` to mock http request:

```
function TestComponent() {
  const mutation = useSubmitform()
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
      { mutation.isError && <p role="alert">failed</p> }
      { mutation.isSuccess && <p role="alert">success</p> }
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
const server = setupServer(
  rest.get('/axios/api', (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.json({message: 'mock server'}))
  }),
)

beforeAll(() => server.listen())
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())
afterAll(() => server.close())

test('test failed', () => {
  server.use(
    // Mock api
    rest.post('/axios/api', (req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(
        ctx.status(500),
        ctx.json({ message: 'Error' }),
      )
    })
  )
  render(<TestComponent />)
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Submit'))
  await waitFor(() => screen.getByRole('alert'))
  expect(screen.getByRole('alert')).toHaveTextContent('failed')
})
```